# Why kafka stream exactly once producer send duplicated records?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I use the kafka stream with exactly once guarantee, however, when I debug it, the producer.commitTransaction doesn't execute, and get rebalanced, but I always get duplicated outputs.

My application is just to filter and re route the topic messages.

This config is like below:

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationId);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootStrapServers);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.Long().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.ByteArray().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "5");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG), "5");
```

Comment: The `producer` you're referring to has a separate thread than your Kafka Streams topology and has its own config, not using `StreamsConfig`. Have you tried adding `enable.idempotence` property to **it**?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes I checked it, the default mode is enable.idempotence = true for exactly once

Comment: Where are you actually calling `producer.commitTransaction`? There's no way for you to access the internal Producer of the Streams API

Comment: @OneCricketeer I debug it, and the commitTransaction wasn't called and through fence exception, and then it retry send, but got two same outputs

Comment: @OneCricketeer after thorough research，I found that my consumer must set the isolation.level to read_committed, then only the commited messages will be consumed, and uncommited messages for unfinished transaction will be ignored

Comment: Ah, yes. Feel free to answer your own question below with those details.